# Two-digit random number is chosen. What is the probability that the sum of its digits is 5?

Tags: probability

I tried this method at first...

Since I know the denominator of the fraction using combinations I include that first: $9C2$.

I am getting stuck at the numerator part of the fraction because there are only $3$ cases $\left(0,5;1,4;2,3,\right)$ right ?.

So the answer I get is $1/12$.
Is the correct? And does order matter in this case ?.

Comment: What is wo-digit?  Since you know the denominator of what?  The numerator part of what?  Only three case of what?

Comment: Two digit numbers range from $10$ to $99$, how many have the sum of digits equal to $5$?

Comment: ${9 \choose 2}$ implies the two digits must be distinct.  Must they?

Comment: Does order matter?  Is 23 the same number as 32?  Is 50 the same number as 05?

Answer (score 5):

Bettween 10- 99 there are 90 two digit numbers.  Of them 14,23,32,41,and 50 have sums adding to 5.

So the probability is $\frac 5{90} = \frac 1{18}$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> A *two-digit number* can be written as $\ds{10a + b}$ where
>   $\ds{a = 1,2,\ldots,9}$ and $\ds{b = 0,1,\ldots,9}$.

\begin{align}
\sum_{a = 1}^{9}{1 \over 9}\sum_{b = 0}^{9}{1 \over 10}\bracks{z^{5}}z^{a + b} & =
{1 \over 90}\bracks{z^{5}}\pars{\sum_{a = 1}^{9}z^{a}}
\pars{\sum_{a = 0}^{9}z^{b}} =
{1 \over 90}\bracks{z^{5}}\pars{z\,{z^{9} - 1 \over z - 1}}
\pars{z^{10} - 1 \over z - 1}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 90}\bracks{z^{4}}{1 - z^{9} - z^{10} + z^{19} \over \pars{1 - z}^{2}} =
{1 \over 90}\bracks{z^{4}}\pars{1 - z}^{-2} =
{1 \over 90}{-2 \choose 4}\pars{-1}^{4}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 90}{5 \choose 4}\pars{-1}^{4} = {1 \over 90}\,5 = \bbx{1 \over 18}
\end{align}